# Why does an array with a variable name of 'names' turn into a string when i put in 'name'?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I declared an array called names. I used a while loop to go over each name and log them into the console.
Then, I accidentally mistyped 'names' into 'name'. Normally, that gives out a **reference error**, but what it logged are the different characters of the first name. And I checked the developer tools and looked for the variable **"name"** because I did not define the variable **"name"

```
 var names = ['John', 'Jane', 'Mary', 'Mark', 'Bob'];

 var i = 0;
 while (i < names.length) {
       console.log(name[i]);
       i++;
 }
```

## What It Printed Out In The Console

```
    J
    o
    h
    n
    ,
```

### Then I looked for  the variable "name" cos I did not declare it and this came out

```
    names
    "John,Jane,Mary,Mark,Bob"
```

#### What is the reason behind this?

Comment: You already declare an array "name"

Comment: it seems there is code missing from this question, as on its own this bevaviour would not occur.

Comment: I’m unable to reproduce this. Just note that `name` in global context is actually `window.name` which is always cast into a string.

Comment: @RenePot it occurs: https://jsfiddle.net/wuhdy3sL/

Comment: @DomeTune there is a typo on `name`. Still the result in fiddle is not the same as the one discribed by Tomy

Comment: @DomeTune That’s not the same output. Why would the OP’s code output `John,`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i added a simple `console.log()` to see what `name` is. In this case we did not define the variable `name`, so it is the default shorthand variable for  `window.name`. This explains the behaviour, that there is no `reference error`. Lets take a closer look to it:

```js
var names = ['John', 'Jane', 'Mary', 'Mark', 'Bob'];

var i = 0;
console.log(name);
var charactersThatWillBeShown = name.substr(0, names.length);
console.log(charactersThatWillBeShown);
var loggedCharacters = "";
while (i < names.length) {
   loggedCharacters += name[i];
   console.log(name[i]);
   i++;
}
console.log(loggedCharacters);
console.log(charactersThatWillBeShown == loggedCharacters);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { 
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Oh window.name!

Comment: Could you give me a bit more info of you window ?

Comment: Where did you entered you Code? Direct in the Console, or in a script loaded into a html file ?

Answer (score 3):

You missed an `s` for `name` in `console.log(name[i]);`.

Change it to `console.log(names[i]);`

Comment: I'm talking about the case of name. I did not define it and it printed out the individual characters of John

Comment: @Tomy try executing `ONLY` the above code snippet in chrome console to verify . It's possible that you may have issued a window.open() before the code (possibly in another js file), or executed your js file from an anchor element in html. These methods affect what appears as properties in the window object, such as `window.name`.

Comment: it's still there.

Answer (score 0):

As I see that you are using name[i] instead of names[i]. If you use names[i] this would be your output [image: This is what you want...]

Comment: I'm talking about the case of name. I did not define it and it printed out the individual characters of `John` .

Comment: But it is showing undefined in chrome console . I don't know why it is showing like that to you